# Getting Attribute error while adding Conv2D in sequential model of Keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 100,3)))
```

input: 100x100 images with 3 channels
32 convolution filters of size 3x3 each
Getting the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8045ebb1a70a> in <module>()
      7 # input: 100x100 images with 3 channels -> (100, 100, 3) tensors.
      8 # this applies 32 convolution filters of size 3x3 each.
----> 9 model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 100, 3)))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.pyc in add(self, layer)
    420                 # and create the node connecting the current layer
    421                 # to the input layer we just created.
--> 422                 layer(x)
    423 
    424             if len(layer.inbound_nodes) != 1:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.pyc in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    552 
    553             # Actually call the layer, collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
--> 554             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
    555             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
    556 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.pyc in call(self, inputs)
    162                 padding=self.padding,
    163                 data_format=self.data_format,
--> 164                 dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate)
    165         if self.rank == 3:
    166             outputs = K.conv3d(

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in conv2d(x, kernel, strides, padding, data_format, dilation_rate)
   2854     x = _preprocess_conv2d_input(x, data_format)
   2855     padding = _preprocess_padding(padding)
-> 2856     x = tf.nn.convolution(
   2857         input=x,
   2858         filter=kernel,

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'convolution'
```

Can anyone help with this? Is this problem because of new distribution keras 2.0?

Comment: Did you upgrade tensorflow? What is the keras version and tf version installed?

Comment: Keras version: **2.0.2** , tensorflow version: **0.11.0**. Is tensorflow **1.0** prerequisite for Keras **2.0**?

Comment: @NassimBen Tried after upgrading to **tensorflow 1.0**. Works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading TensorFlow to **TensorFlow 1.0** is **prerequisite** for **Keras 2.0**.
Though it is not mentioned on Keras Official site.

Above problem is resolved by just upgrading to Tensorflow 1.0

To Upgrade Tensorflow follow this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/).